# Socket io from laravel to flutter

Tags: laravel, socket.io, flutter

I am trying to do real time app with socket io.

I am able to connect my socket io in my laravel server and the laravel frontend by follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-echo-server-how-to-24d5778ece8b).

I have connect with the event with code below from my frontend.

```
<script>
    window.Echo.channel('test-event')
        .listen('ExampleEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
</script>
```

As the code above from frontend can tell I have a channel call test-event and listen to ExampleEvent from laravel.

I wanted to have a listener to this event in my flutter app. I have chose this [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_flutter_plugin) in order to try to connect my laravel socket but it seem like it does not work as good as I think.

Below is the code from my flutter app so far.

```
SocketFlutterPlugin myIO;

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initPlatformState();
  }

Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
  try {
    myIO = new SocketFlutterPlugin();
    myIO.socket("http://localhost:6001");
    myIO.connect();
    // String jsonData =
    //         '{"content":"test"}';
    // myIO.emit("test-event",jsonData);
    myIO.on("test-event",(data){
      print("its here");
    });
  } on PlatformException {
    _platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
  }
}
```

There are two problems that I have encountered and need some advice from you guys.

First: I do not know if I have connected to my laravel socket successfully.

Second: As I mentioned for laravel frontend I have one channel and one listener, but this package in flutter seem like only have channel to connect to.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying the same thing as me which wanted to connect to socket io from flutter to laravel.

This [package](https://github.com/kakajansh/echo) can help you.